# Css Issue When Scroll is applied for bootstrap drop down menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have large list in my dropdown menu. so I have applied scroll to it. I want to show my dropdown menu always on top of link.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="clean-dropdown">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" id="add-more">
  add more
</a> 
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-list">
  <li><a href="#" >1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">5</a></li><li><a href="#">6</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">8</a></li><li><a href="#">8</a></li><li><a href="#">10</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">12</a></li><li><a href="#">13</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">14</a></li><li><a href="#">15</a></li><li><a href="#">16</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">17</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#dropdown-list{
max-height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
top: 15px;
position: relative;
left: 50px
}

#add-more{
top: 224px;
position: relative;
```

}

Here is the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/141/

Problem is when I click on add more link dropdown shows. Dont move the cursor. The last item is shown as selected and this happens only in chrome.

[image]

If we see in console. Then li's are out of dropdown menu. I think thats why the last item is being shown as selected.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: this seems kinda trivial...why does it matter if the user has to move the mouse to select something anyways? and I can't reproduce this on  30.0.1599.66 m

Comment: @DavidNguyen Nguyen: I am using 30.0.1599.66 m version only. I have tested the fiddle in this version and it is replicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element in dropdown is selected because li's are out of dropdown. Even if we focus on Add more it is being overridden by the focus of li's and getting selected.

To fix this issue I have removed the `box-shadow` in css. It did trick for me.

```
#dropdown-list{
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
 top: 33px;
 position: relative;
 left: 50px;
 box-shadow: none;
 }
```

Here is the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/158/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your `max-height: 200px;` if you check the mouse pointer (under chrome) you will see the focus area of your last li is far outside your dropdown (caused by the z-index?). In some cases this area will overlap your "add" link.

To prevent set you `max-height:` according the number of items you want to show. For example for 7 items set `max-height:` to 7 x 26 (default height of a li in the dropdown) + 5 (default padding of the ul) 187px;

Comment: Li is outside of dropdown and it is overlapping  the "add more" link. to fix this I have removed the dropdown menu box shadow and it did the trick. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting `position:relative` on the list items seems to solve the issue:

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/52VtD/160/)**

Comment: using Position: relative fixed in the fiddle. But not in my application :-) . Various ways to solve problems. Hope it help others.